# Iteration causes crash

Tags: c++, c

What is wrong with this iteration?
This particular piece of code is causing my program to crash. When I disable the code it works but of course giving wrong results. It's supposed to compare `sigma` with `sigma_last` until they remain equal at `e-14`.

This is what I tried first:

```
long double sigma_last = NULL;

       do{
         if(sigma_last != NULL){
            sigma = sigma_last;
         }
         sigma1 = atan( tan(beta1) / cos(A1) );
         sigmaM = (2*sigma1 + sigma) / 2;

         d_sigma = B*sin(sigma)*(cos(2*sigmaM)+(1/4)*B*(cos(sigma)
                         *(-1+2*pow(cos(2*sigmaM),2)))-(1/6)*B*cos(2*sigmaM)
                         *(-3+4*pow(sin(sigma),2))*(-3+4*pow(cos(2*sigmaM),2)));
         sigma_last = sigma + d_sigma;
       }
       while(set_precision_14(sigma)<= set_precision_14(sigma_last) || set_precision_14(sigma)>= set_precision_14(sigma_last));
```

Then I tried using a pointer (desperately):

```
long double *sigma_last;
*sigma_last = NULL;
   do{
      if(*sigma_last != NULL){
        sigma = *sigma_last;
     }
     sigma1 = atan( tan(beta1) / cos(A1) );
     sigmaM = (2*sigma1 + sigma) / 2;

     d_sigma = B*sin(sigma)*(cos(2*sigmaM)+(1/4)*B*(cos(sigma)
                     *(-1+2*pow(cos(2*sigmaM),2)))-(1/6)*B*cos(2*sigmaM)
                     *(-3+4*pow(sin(sigma),2))*(-3+4*pow(cos(2*sigmaM),2)));
     *sigma_last = sigma + d_sigma;
   }
   while(set_precision_14(sigma)<= set_precision_14(*sigma_last) || set_precision_14(sigma)>= set_precision_14(*sigma_last));
```

Finding the source of error in entire code and trying to solve it took me hours, cannot really come up with another *"maybe this?"* . Feel free to smite me.

Here's a github link to my [full code](https://github.com/Peytuk/geodEasy.c/blob/master/Vincenty%2B%2B.cpp) if anyone out there's interested.

Comment: You know that e.g. `1/4` and `1/6` are *integer divisions*, whose result will be *zero*?

Comment: Regarding your pointer version, `sigma_last` will *always* be a null pointer, which you can never dereference.

Comment: `long double sigma_last = NULL;` (a pointer?)

Comment: Consider `set_precision_14(sigma)<= set_precision_14(sigma_last) || set_precision_14(sigma)>= set_precision_14(sigma_last)` - it takes the form `x <= y || x >= y` - I don't even need to know how `set_precision_14` works to know that condition will always be true, so the loop will never terminate / your program will hang.  Regarding 1/4 and 1/6, you can fix that by making either or both of the numbers doubles: e.g. `1.0/4` and `1.0/6`.

Comment: *Finding the source of error in entire code and trying to solve it took me hours* -- And it took @Some literally 5 minutes to find your integer division mistake.   You could help yourself by breaking up your calculation into several pieces, so as to see which one breaks.

Comment: Further to Paul's comment, invest in learning to use an interactive debugger and stepping through your code line by line to see where the behaviour deviates from your expectations/hopes: that will tell you where something needs fixing.

Comment: @Peytuk: *"sigma is not always greater or less then sigma_last"* - but at any given iteration of the loop, it's momentarily either greater, equal, or less, and any of those relationships will let your loop continue to iterate.  Anyway, to fix it you might want to do something vaguely like `} while (abs(sigma - sigma_last) < abs(sigma * 1E-14));`.

Comment: @TonyDelroy Now I understand what you mean! :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first (and only) iteration, `sigma_last` will be null, resulting in crash:

```
*sigma_last = NULL; // <-- dereferencing uninitialized ptr here
if(*sigma_last != NULL) { // <-- dereferencing uninitialized ptr here too
```

and if that would have been fixed, here:

```
*sigma_last == sigma + d_sigma;
```

This is because you have not set `sigma_last` to point to some valid floating-point space in memory. There doesn't seem to be any point to using a pointer in this particular case, so if I were you, I'd drop it and use a normal `long double` instead, as in your first attempt.

In your first example you assign NULL, which is really the value zero, to `sigma_last`. If zero is not what you're intending, you could either go with a value that most certainly will be out of range (say `1e20` and then compare to say `< 1e19`) or keep a separate boolan for the job. I personally prefer the first option:

```
long double sigma_last = 1e20;
...
if(sigma_last < 1e19){
    sigma = sigma_last;
}
```

A better way still would be to use an infinite, or finite, loop and then break out at a certain condition. This will make the code easier to read.

### Logic

Finally, you seem to have a problem with your logic in the `while`, since the comparison `sigma <= sigma_last || sigma >= sigma_last` is *always* true. It's always smaller, bigger, or equal.

Comment: Shouldn't the error have occurred at `if(*sigma_last != NULL){`, seeing as he is attempting to use the value at that memory address when the line before set the pointer to NULL?

Comment: @smac89: True that. I'll fix.

Comment: In addition, the code invokes what I believe to be UB here `*sigma_last = NULL;` (just above the if-statement I mentioned above)

Comment: `*sigma_last = NULL;` at this point `sigma` is not _necessarily_ `NULL`, but it might as well be because you don't know what it is pointing at

Comment: my `while` logic was a total disaster. I made changes according to your suggestions, cheers. @JonasByström

Answer (score 1):

sigma_last does not need to be a pointer. You just need to somehow flag its value to know whether it was already set or not. From your code I am not sure if we can use zero for this purpose, but we can use some constant (long double minimum value), like this one:

```
#include <float.h>
const long double invalid_constant = LDBL_MIN;
```

Try this:

```
long double DESTINATION_CALCULATION_plusplus ( double phi, double lambda, double S, double azimuth,
            double a, double b, double *phi2, double* lambda2, double* azimuth2){

    phi = phi*M_PI/180;
    lambda = lambda*M_PI/180;
    double A1;
    double eu2 = (pow(a, 2) - pow(b, 2)) / pow(b, 2); //second eccentricity
    double c = pow(a,2) / b;
    double v = sqrt(1 + (eu2 * pow(cos(phi) , 2)));
    double beta1 = tan(phi) / v;
    double Aeq = asin( cos(beta1) * sin(azimuth) );
    double f = (a - b) / a; //flattening
    double beta = atan((1-f)*tan(phi));
    double u2 = pow(cos(Aeq),2)*eu2;
    //////////////////////////////----------------------------------------------
    long double sigma1 = atan( tan(beta1)/ cos(azimuth) );
    long double A = 1 + u2*(4096 + u2*(-768+u2*(320-175*u2))) / 16384;
    long double B = u2*(256 + u2*(-128+u2*(74-47*u2)))/1024;
    long double sigma = S /  (b*A);
    long double sigmaM = (2*sigma1 + sigma) /2;
    long double d_w;
    long double d_sigma;
    ////////////////////////////------------------------------------------------
    double C;
    double d_lambda;
    long double sigma_last=invalid_constant;
       do{
          if(sigma_last != invalid_constant){
            sigma = sigma_last;
         }
         sigma1 = atan( tan(beta1) / cos(A1) );
         sigmaM = (2*sigma1 + sigma) / 2;

         d_sigma = B*sin(sigma)*(cos(2*sigmaM)+(1/4)*B*(cos(sigma)
                         *(-1+2*pow(cos(2*sigmaM),2)))-(1/6)*B*cos(2*sigmaM)
                         *(-3+4*pow(sin(sigma),2))*(-3+4*pow(cos(2*sigmaM),2)));
         sigma_last = sigma + d_sigma;
       }
       while(set_precision_14(sigma)<= set_precision_14(sigma_last) || set_precision_14(sigma)>= set_precision_14(sigma_last));

       sigma = sigma_last;
       *phi2 = atan((sin(beta1)*cos(sigma)+cos(beta1)*sin(sigma)*cos(azimuth))/((1-f)
       *sqrt(pow(sin(Aeq),2)+pow((sin(beta1)*sin(sigma)-cos(beta1)*cos(sigma)*cos(azimuth)),2))));

        d_w = (sin(sigma)*sin(azimuth))/(cos(beta1)*cos(sigma) - sin(beta1)* sin(sigma)*cos(azimuth));
        C   = (f/16)*pow(cos(Aeq),2)*(4+f*(4-3*pow(cos(Aeq),2)));
        d_lambda = d_w - (1-C)*f*sin(azimuth)*(sigma + C*sin(sigma)*
                   (cos(2*sigmaM)+C*cos(sigma)*(-1+2*pow(cos(2*sigmaM),2))));

        *lambda2 = lambda + d_lambda;
        *azimuth2 = sin(Aeq) / (-sin(beta1)*sin(sigma)+cos(beta1)*cos(sigma)*cos(azimuth));

        *azimuth2 = *azimuth2 * 180/M_PI;
        *lambda2 = *lambda2 * 180/M_PI;
        *phi2 = *phi2 * 180/M_PI;

}
```